# How to transfer gpg keys to another computer?

Tags: git, gnupg

I'd like to transfer my gpg public and private keys so that I can sign Git commits from my Raspberry Pi. When I try `gpg  --armor --export-secret-key KEY_ID | ssh pi@bb8 gpg --import`, I am prompted for my GPG and Pi Password. However, I get the following error after that:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: File format issue? (https://serverfault.com/q/119608/783)